# autoit ControlClick Does not work if the title is in Hebrew

Tags: autoit

I'm a bit stuck and I need help
I try to run with autoit controlclick and put under "title" the title of the window but for some reason it is not clicked.
I think because the title is in Hebrew then the autoit does not recognize the window
I can not work by location (muoseclick) because the script will run on different screens

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: What does `WinGetTitle("[ACTIVE]")` give you when it is selected? Have you tried the Window Info Tool?

Comment: I use info tools and it finds the title but when I run the script it seems to me that it does not find the window

The title is "בחירת תצורה" and the command I run is:
ControlClick ("בחירת תצורה", "", "class")

It works for me on a window whose title is in English so it does not seem to me that I'm not writing it right

Comment: Is it a right to left language so you have to reverse the letters? Just guessing...